# H2 user-defined function is called many times

Tags: java, database, h2, recursive-query, h2db

I'm using the h2 v1.3.176.
I have user-defined function which execute RECURSIVE query.

```java
public static ResultSet getChildCategories(Connection connection, long categoryId) throws SQLException {
    String sql = 
            "WITH RECURSIVE r(CATEGORY_ID, PARENT_ID) AS (\n" +
            "    SELECT   CATEGORY_ID\n" +
            "            ,PARENT_ID\n" +
            "    FROM     CATEGORY\n" +
            "    WHERE    CATEGORY_ID = " + categoryId + "\n" +
            "    UNION ALL\n" +
            "    SELECT   CATEGORY.CATEGORY_ID\n" +
            "            ,CATEGORY.PARENT_ID\n" +
            "    FROM     CATEGORY, r\n" +
            "    WHERE    CATEGORY.PARENT_ID = r.CATEGORY_ID\n" +
            ")\n" +
            "SELECT CATEGORY_ID FROM r";
    ResultSet resultSet = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(sql);
    SimpleResultSet rs = new SimpleResultSet();
    rs.addColumn("CATEGORY_ID", Types.INTEGER, 12, 0);
    try {
        while(resultSet.next()) {
            rs.addRow(resultSet.getLong(1));
        }
    } finally {
        resultSet.close();
    }
    return rs;
}
```

I have registered this function by following SQL.

```
create alias GET_CHILD_CATEGORIES for "com.myapp.db.function.Functions.getChildCategories";
```

My problem is the `getChildCategories` function will be called many times when I execute the following query.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT  B.BOOK_ID
                ,B.SERIES_ID
                ,B.TITLE
                ,B.ISBN
                ,B.VOLUME
                ,(
                    SELECT  MAX(SAME_SERIES.VOLUME)
                    FROM    BOOK SAME_SERIES
                    WHERE   SAME_SERIES.SERIES_ID = B.SERIES_ID
                    AND     SAME_SERIES.VOLUME IS NOT NULL
                ) AS VOLUME_COUNT
                ,B.PAGE_COUNT
                ,B.FILE_PATH
                ,B.SORTABLE_FILE_NAME
                ,B.SIZE
                ,B.HASH
                ,B.COVER_IMAGE_TYPE
                ,B.COVER_PAGE_NO
                ,B.COVER_LARGE_IMAGE_URL
                ,B.COVER_SMALL_IMAGE_URL
                ,B.COVER_CROP_COORD
                ,B.IS_ENCRYPT
                ,B.PUBLISHER_ID
                ,B.PUBLISHED_DATE
                ,B.CREATION_TIME
                ,B.LAST_MODIFIED_TIME
                ,B.NOTE
                ,B.IS_ISBN_SEARCH
                ,S.CATEGORY_ID
                ,S.TITLE
                ,BA.AUTHOR_ID
                ,BT.TAG_ID
FROM             BOOK AS B
INNER JOIN       SERIES AS S ON S.SERIES_ID = B.SERIES_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN  BOOK_TAG AS BT ON BT.BOOK_ID = B.BOOK_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN  BOOK_AUTHOR AS BA ON BA.BOOK_ID = B.BOOK_ID
WHERE 
(
    S.CATEGORY_ID IN (SELECT CATEGORY_ID FROM GET_CHILD_CATEGORIES(106))
    And 
    S.IS_COMPLETION = 1
)
ORDER BY  BA.AUTHOR_ID
```

Why do many times would be called this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracted from [H2 documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions)

> A function that returns a result set can be used like a table.
>   However, in this case the function is called at least twice: first
>   while parsing the statement to collect the column names (with
>   parameters set to null where not known at compile time). And then,
>   while executing the statement to get the data (maybe multiple times if
>   this is a join). If the function is called just to get the column
>   list, the URL of the connection passed to the function is
>   jdbc:columnlist:connection. Otherwise, the URL of the connection is
>   jdbc:default:connection.

The first calls are only to retrieve the resultset column types. Then you have to check if the connection url is "jdbc:columnlist:connection". If true you have to return an empty result set with column list.

The connection url test is:

```
connection.getMetaData().getURL().equals("jdbc:columnlist:connection");
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! It's just as you said.
I was able to improve the query performance.

Comment: Good stuff! Still applies in version 1.4.200.

Comment: H2 2.1.214 here with simpleJdbcCall.execute(). I see 'jdbc:columnlist:connection' on both calls - when parameters are not set and when they are set.
When using jdbcTemplate.execute(), the function gets called with parameters set on both calls. And the URL is 'jdbc:columnlist:connection' on both calls, as well.